# space combat for a BTE 4x game game

Tags: weapons, vehicles, games

l am currently writing a game - I'm making a racing table top game with high tech weapons. What's a weapon that would shoot through people that isn't just a high powered cannon? It doesn't have to be functional today because this is set far in the future.

Comment: Please make sure to read and understand our [help], in particular the sections about asking and answering questions. We request answers to, not surprisingly, answer the questions, and questions should be well scoped: this is lacking in your post at the moment

Comment: How much energy do we get to throw and what do you base your selection for best answer on? With your current question I could say "a micro black hole" or "antimatter stream" and fulfill your requirements. That would be massive overkill compared to, say, a laserrifle that fires a thousand pulses in a fraction of a fraction of a second with X wattage to dig through the target.

Comment: "Shoot through" could also imply some sort of phase-shifting or teleporting projectile that can travel through one vehicle and the hit/materialize inside another vehicle. If it's simply to blow a thin hole through something and out the other, almost any beam weapon could work.

Comment: Also, what kind of vehicles are racing? Cars? Space battlecruisers? Giant monsters (you had the biology tag, but the question said nothing about biology)? Do you mean shoot through people, or vehicles?

Comment: What are your functional requirements for "not a high powered cannon"? Merely ascetics (e.g. its not "hi tech" enough), or are you actually looking for some game play interactions, and if so, what kind of things are you thinking of?

Comment: We love helping game designers develop their games, but you seem to be at the wrong stage for our assistance. "Weapons" in a game are just window dressing, part of the story. Our [help/on-topic] says, "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story." What this means is that we'll help you develop the rules governing your weapons and how they're used in your game - but we won't help you with naming or describing your weapons, because that's just window dressing. You'll find more, very important rules at [help/dont-ask].

Comment: BTE is a very common acronym in various lexicons https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/BtE.  Since this is not a gaming specific exchange, I would suggest you define what you mean by BTE 4x better.

Comment: l need help  please help me

Comment: @E.J We are happy to help.  Read the comments listed so far and modify your question to include details answering the questions people have commented about like are these people in space or space ships? What is BTE 4x? etc.  Once your question is clear enough, we can vote to reopen the question for people to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Harpoon!**

A harpoon can go right through another vehicle.  Then you have got it.
The beauty of the harpoon is that you can then use the mass of the vehicle you have harpooned to pull yourself forward while you pull it back, slinging yourself ahead of the harpooned one (this is racing, right?) while disadvantaging your competitor.

Comment: Very fun idea for a racing videogame, but probably not the choice I would go with for a "high tech weapon" that can "shoot through people".  Sounded more like he was looking for a sci-fi weapon that would achieve an over-penetration mechanic.

Comment: @Nosajimiki: a struggled to reconcile racing tabletop with space combat.  I envisioned something like Mario Karts where it is a race but you have offensive capabilities.   An attack that gave you a speed boost at the expense of competition is something I have not seen in racing games and something that would work well on the tabletop,  and a harpoon fit the request for a penetrating attack.